# array.GetLength throws out of range exception for a multidimensional array

Tags: c#

I have this simple code.

```
        int[][] array = {
                    new int[] {1,2,3},
                    new int[] {4,5,6},
                  };

        int yLength = array.GetLength(1);
```

But the last line throws an out of range exception. Why is that?
Shouldn't it `GetLength` return 3 in this case? Or is GetLength only applicable to square arrays? (T[,] array)?
If so, how do I loop through jagged arrays with  a `for` loop?

Comment: This last line will not throw OOR. cannot repro. Closing.

Comment: It works on my side...

Comment: Your code works as expected, there is no error.

Comment: Sorry, A mistake on the code. I will edit it

Comment: Okay, now it returns Out of range exception. So I would like to know how to loop through the array with a for loop. Sorry for the inconveniences. (My text book didn't really teach me looping through jagged arrays)

Comment: You are creating array of arrays, not n-dimensional array. That's why array.GetLength(1) is throwing exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As internal arrays can have different size you can't use `array.GetLength(1)`, use `array[i].Length` instead to get the length of a particular array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think of that before ;)

Answer (score 6):

- You are creating an array of arrays, not an n-dimensional array. These are the same things in C but not in C#. That's why `array.GetLength(1)` is throwing an exception.

  The [`Array.Rank` MSDN page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/multidimensional-array) gives a syntax example and the comparison of the two ways:

  ```
   int[] array1 = new int[10];
   int[,] array2= new int[10,3];  
   int[][] array3 = new int[10][]; 

   Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} dimension(s)", 
                     array1.ToString(), array1.Rank); // System.Int32[]: 1 dimension(s)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} dimension(s)", 
                     array2.ToString(), array2.Rank); // System.Int32[,]: 2 dimension(s)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} dimension(s)", 
                     array3.ToString(), array3.Rank); // System.Int32[][]: 1 dimension(s)
  ```
- As arrays implement `IEnumerable`, you can simply use `foreach`:

  ```
   foreach (var innerArray in array)
     foreach (var elem in innerArray)
       Console.WriteLine(elem);
  ```

  Or use LINQ on them, keeping in mind that it is an array of nested arrays.